# How can I open my project in Zend? I accidentally removed it from the left pane

Tags: php, zend-studio

I accidentally removed the application from the left pane and now I can't get it back no matter what I do.

I tried opening the .solution file from within Zend Studio, but it only loads the file, not the entire solution.

How can I have it load the **entire** application?

**Edit:**
I still can't what to open. In Visual Studio, you can open a project file, and that loads everything necessary in the application. Why is Zend so complicated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to locate your Zend Studio Profile inside your home directory. This IDE stores sometimes (when no other configuration is set) the project infos there.

Answer (score 3):

are you talking about a project within zend studio or your entire profile? If its a project click file->import, under the general tab theres "existing project into workspace" and point that to root folder of the missing project.

if you want your entire profile (workspace), click file switch workspace and you should have a folder called workspace in your documents folder.

If you are just missing the project window, click window->show view-> php explorer

hope this helps